# Sum up all previous values in column

Tags: r, dplyr

I feel like this questions should have been answered before, but I fail to find the answer. I want to do a very simple operation in R with a data frame: For each row in ascending order, I want to sum up all the values above (i.e. make a total up to this observation). However, using lag(), I fail to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at `cumsum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew Gustar mentions, e.g.,

```
cars <- mtcars
cumcyl <- cumsum(cars$cyl)
cars <- cbind(cars, cumcyl)
```

Comment: or just `cars$cumcyl <- cumsum(cars$cyl)`, no need for the intermediate variable.